# {@inheritdoc} replaced by @ERROR

Tags: php, eclipse, code-formatting, inheritdoc

I have recently installed Eclipse for PHP on a new laptop and checked out packages from TYPO3.Flow, but whenever I use the "format this file" option in Eclipse, it will replace every instance of {@inheritdoc} in the comment annotations above properties/methods with @ERROR!!! (including the exclamation marks)

I have tried in PHPStorm, and the behaviour does not occur there; the {@inheritdoc} annotations are simply ignored.

I have never seen this before, nor can I find anything about it on google. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug is fixed in latest Eclipse PDT,

Eclipse Bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=418890